# How to parse CSV file with UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, unicode

I use Spark 2.1.

input csv file contains unicode characters like shown below

[image: unicode-input-csv]

While parsing this csv file, the output is shown like below

[image: unicode-output-csv]

I use MS Excel 2010 to view files.

The Java code used is

```
@Test
public void TestCSV() throws IOException {
    String inputPath = "/user/jpattnaik/1945/unicode.csv";
    String outputPath = "file:\\C:\\Users\\jpattnaik\\ubuntu-bkp\\backup\\bug-fixing\\1945\\output-csv";
    getSparkSession()
      .read()
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
      .csv(inputPath)
      .write()
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .csv(outputPath);
}
```

How can I get the output same as input?

Comment: Thanks @Jacek, I checked the file encoding using file command and got to know the encoding of file is actually ISO-8859-1, So I parsed this file accordingly and got desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My *guess* is that the input file is not in `UTF-8` and hence you get the incorrect characters.

My recommendation would be to write a pure Java application (with no Spark at all) and see if reading and writing gives the same results with `UTF-8` encoding.

Answer (score 18):

I was able to read ISO-8859-1 using spark but when I store the same data to S3/hdfs back and read it, the format is converting to UTF-8.

ex: `é to Ã©`

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", ",").option("ESCAPE quote", '"'). option("header",true).option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1").load("s3://bucket/folder")
```

Comment: Can some one help me to save the ISO-8859-1 format data to aws S3/hdfs.

Comment: An answer is not the correct place to ask a question. You should create a new question.

Comment: In case someone here is trying to read an Excel CSV file into Spark, there is an option in Excel to save the CSV using UTF-8 encoding. If you use this option to store the CSV, you don't need to specify the encoding as ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 2):

.option('encoding', 'ISO-8859-1') worked for me. Acute, caret, cedilla accents among others appeared correctly.