# spark.sparkContext.textFile read a file using UTF-8 encoding

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, encode

I am trying to read a file using `spark.sparkContext.textFile`. The file is in unicode encoded. when I read the file some of the chars are as below:

> 2851 K�RNYE HUNGARY
>
> 2851 K�RNYE HUNGARY

how to read a file to rdd be specifying encoding mode.

Answer (score 1):

Using `SparkContext.binaryFiles()` should help. You just need to build the content specifying the relevant charset.

The example below is for ISO_8859:

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles(filePath, 12)
  .mapValues(content => new String(content.toArray(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))
  .toDF
```

More info [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#binaryFiles-java.lang.String-int-).

Comment: Thanks ! My source is a multi delimited file encoded with uTF-8.   when i tried the above option i get the output as 
|_1                                                      |_2                                                                                                                                                                                             
|file:/C:/Senthil/SenStudy/Scala/Files/multidelimiter.txt|input!~outout!~value!~count
senthil!~nathan!~is!~here
how to convert it to normal rows and columns [like normal dataframe]

Comment: @senthilnathan this is probably what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/46914895/4528242