# How to read ñ with pyspark from a csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pyspark, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to read Non-Ascii characters from a csv in pysaprk, specifically the csv contains names of countries in spanish, so I have `ESPAÑA` (SPAIN in spanish), but it reads `ESPA�OLA`

this is the code I am using:

```
df = sqlContext.read.csv("path", sep=",", header=True )
```

I can't find all the encodings that `sqlContext.read` accepts, i was trying to use `latin-1` but I get a message that it is not supported

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to convert your file to UTF-8 encoding **before** loading it with read.csv()?

Other possibly related question:
[How to parse CSV file with UTF-8 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002651/how-to-parse-csv-file-with-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: I saw that post, but what I understand is that there is no option to read this characters with spark, so is that correct? I want to read them using spark (if it is possible)

Comment: Try to run with the parameter encoding="iso-8859"
If it still says it's not supported, then your safest bet is to convert your file to UTF-8 first.
This might help in that regard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191359/how-to-convert-a-file-to-utf-8-in-python

Comment: Yes that encoding says it is not supported, Thanks